$p$-wave superconducting spectrum: why is $\Delta$ the superconducting gap?
My question might be silly but, the spectrum of a $p$-wave superconductor is
$$
E(k) = \sqrt{ \left(\mu + 2\lambda \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{N} k \right)\right)^2 + 4 \sin\left(k\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)^2 |\Delta|^2}, \quad \quad k=1,\cdots,N
$$
with $\mu$ the chemical potential, $\lambda$ the hopping amplitude and $\Delta$ the "superconducting gap", see Kitaev.
So I dont get it, what opens a gap in the spectrum is $\mu$ and/or $\lambda$ not $\Delta$, the role of $\Delta$ is to "stretch" the spectrum upwards.
Hence my question: Why do people call it the superconducting gap?

Also perhaps related, now that I am at it, this suggests that creating a single quasi-particle with zero momentum takes a finite amount of energy. What does that mean?

If you plot the E(k) relation, you will see that only for finite $\Delta$ the spectrum is gapped.
